# Center text vertically and horizontally in div, when the div background image is responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wonder how i can align my h2 to center of the div when the height is adjusteble. I know how to do it when i have a height in px. Then i just write like this

```
 height: 300px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
```

But i have no clue how to do it in a responsive div image.

This is my code http://www.bootply.com/yr5KNSM17S# 
and this is how i want my text to be http://www.bootply.com/HIbKwupnLb

Sorry if im unclear.

```
<div id="mainHeaderWrapper">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x400/cf5">
   <div>
          <h2 class="vit text-center">Testing text</h2>
   </div>
</div>




#mainHeaderWrapper{
    position:relative;
    background: no-repeat url(http://placehold.it/1500x400/cf5) 50% / 100%;
}
#mainHeaderWrapper > img{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%; /* max width */
    opacity: 0;  /* make it transparent */
}
#mainHeaderWrapper > div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#mainHeaderWrapper h2{
 align-items: center;
}

h2.vit{
    color: white;
    font: 900 24px/24px "Raleway",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 1; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you. You can add `position: absolute` on `h2` tag for vertical alignment. Like below.

```
#mainHeaderWrapper h2{
 align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
```

Comment: @Moe , If we add top: 50% on any tag we need to add negative margin against this for vertical alignment. For example #mainHeaderWrapper h2 height is 44px if you divide this with 2 you got 22px thats why I add -22px in this class.

Comment: Ok thank you, i give u a thumb up. Tho do u know how i make the h2 background like it is on the other one? Since this one gets 100% width, i just want it as big as h2 is

Comment: i suggest you to remove extra lime color background from image and give this color through background-color property and then give background-size: cover; for bigger image.